# scale_color_manual colors won't change

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to change the colors in a plot manually but

My code with dummydata:

```
df2=data.frame(y=runif(10), ontopic=c(F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,T))

plot_right <- ggplot(df2, aes(y, fill = ontopic)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + 
     coord_flip()  + theme(legend.position = "none")+
     scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.5))+
     scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00"))
plot_right
```

This returns the standard colors. What do I need to do to change the colors to my manual selection?

Comment: color != fill, try `scale_fill_manual` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using scale_fill_manual instead of scale_colour_manual should work.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(y, fill = ontopic, colour= ontopic)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + 
  coord_flip()  + theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00"))
```

[image]